# Help distinguishing between factorials, $^nC_r$ and $^nP_r$

Tags: combinatorics

I am having trouble distinguishing when to use factorials, $^nC_r$ and $^nP_r$.

I am considering this description of their various purposes:

"Factorials serve two purposes, both stated above: the number of ways to order a set of $n$ objects is $n! $, and this makes it useful in other formulas. What you call "$^nC_r$" stands for combinations - the number of ways to choose $r$ objects from a set of $n$ distinguishable objects, where order doesn't matter. Contrast this with $^nP_r$, which is the number of ways to choose $r$ objects from a set of $n$ distinguishable objects when order does matter."

I don't really understand what is meant by 'order matters.'

Comment: Order matters means that $abc$ and $bca$ are different selections.

Comment: @agra94 Please note the tag description for probability-theory: "Use this tag only if your question is about the modern theoretical footing for probability, for example probability spaces, random variables, law of large numbers, and central limit theorems."

Answer (score 1):

C is for combination, and P for permutation. Think of C as a group and P as a list.

Answer (score 1):

Chosing $r$ items from a set of $n$ can be done in

- $^nP_r=n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-r+1)=\dfrac{n!}{(n-r)!}$ ways when order matters, because you choose among $n$, then among $n-1$, then $n-2$, ... down to $n-r+1$.
- $^nC_r=\dfrac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}=\dfrac{^nP_r}{r!}$ ways when order doesn't matter, because every selection appears exactly $r!$ times, by permutation.

Two limit cases can be considered.

- when $r=0$, you can choose no element in a single way, and $^nP_r=^nC_r=1$.
- when $r=n$, you choose all elements in $^nP_r=n!$ ways when order matters, and in a single way, $^nC_n=1$ otherwise, as you simply pick them all.

---

Examples:

$^3P_2=6:ab,ac,ba,bc,ca,cb$

$^3C_2=\dfrac62=3:ab,ac,bc$

$^3P_3=6:abc,acb,bac,bca,cab,cba$

$^3C_3=\dfrac66=1:abc$

Comment: @learnandshare: if you change the notation, change it in the OP as well.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have $5$ objects in the set $S=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

A permutation defines an ordering in the whole set of $5$ elements:

$\{1,2,5,4\},\{1,4,2,5\},\{1,4,5,2\}...$ and the total orderings is $5!$

A combination for example $5C3$ chooses $3$ objects from the total of $5$ objects:

$\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,4\},\{1,2,5\}...$ but since order does not matter, $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{3,2,1\}$ is the same group and its formula is $\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$

If order matters, then $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{3,2,1\}$ are different, this is called permutation of a combination and its formula is $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$. Note that you are permuting each combination, that is why the $r!$ factorial of the denominator is canceled.

Answer (score 0):

I will just give a short explanation on that. 
For combinations the $\textbf{orders do not matter}$. For example there are $4$ person we need to choose $2$ of them so we use $^4C_2$ to obtain $6$.

Let the $4$ person be $p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4$, we have choosen $2$ from $4$ so the combinations are as follows:

$(p_1,p_2),$$(p_3,p_4),$$(p_2,p_3),$$(p_2,p_4),$$(p_1,p_4),$$(p_1,p_3)$

Now, let's move on to permutation. Suppose we need to permutate $2$ out of the $4$ person, mathematically it is written as $^4P_2$ to obtain $12$. In this case $\textbf{order matters}$, the permuations are as follows:

$(p_1,p_2),$$(p_3,p_4),$$(p_2,p_3),$$(p_2,p_4),$$(p_1,p_4),$$(p_1,p_3)$,$(p_2,p_1),$$(p_4,p_3),$$(p_3,p_2),$$(p_4,p_2),$$(p_4,p_1),$$(p_3,p_1)$